# Generate a pdf that downloads with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I have a application built with Angular JS, I would like to have a button that generates and downloads a pdf of a div area (this is just binded data)

[This is close to what I would like, but it does not outline how this would be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072351/angular-js-generating-pdf-any-creator-maker-modules)

Any help would be great, I have also tried jsPDF but that does not work well with Angular.

Comment: well, have you tried something? if you did, what went wrong? please provide a Minimal, Concise and Valid example of what you're trying to do that is not working. Because jsPDF within angular is definitely working, and it's working really great!

Answer (score 0):

I have jsPDF working great within an angular application:

```
angular.module('YourApp')
  .factory('InvoiceGenerator', function() {
    return {
      makeInvoice: function(subject, reference, from, to, /* whatever you need to print out... */ ) {
        getLogo(window.location.origin+'/images/bot-objects-full-logo.png',
          function(imgData) {
            var doc = new window.jsPDF();
            var x=0, y=0;

            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10, 50, 15);

            doc.setFontSize(12);
            x=10;y=30;
            from.forEach(function(line) {
              doc.text(x, y, line);
              y += 5;
            });

            x=145;y=50;
            to.forEach(function(line) {
              doc.text(x, y, line);
              y += 5;
            });

            x=10;y=80; doc.text(x, y, 'Subject: '+subject);
            y+=5;      doc.text(x, y, 'Reference: '+reference);

            doc.setLineWidth(0.5);
            y=110;     doc.line(20, y, 180, y); // horizontal line

            /* do whatever you need to do with the other sutff you need to print out ... */

            doc.save('foo.pdf');
          });
       }
    }
}
```

then that code can be used across your project:

```
.controller('YourAppController',
   ['$scope', 'InvoiceGenerator', 
   function($scope, InvoiceGenerator)) {
    $scope.printInvoice = function(invoice) {
        InvoiceGenerator.makeInvoice('This is an invoice',
                                     'IV1234', 
                                     ['Your firm',
                                      'your street',
                                      'your city',
                                      'your country'
                                     ], 
                                     ['Your client',
                                      'his street',
                                      'his city',
                                      'his country'
                                     ],
                                     /* 'other stuff you want to printout' */
                                     )
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is complete it according to *your* needs, and use it wherever you need.

So your assertion *"I have also tried jsPDF but that does not work well with Angular."* is wrong, you might just have an issue, so you should follow SO's way and show what you have tried to help us help you solve your issues.

Comment: I tried implementing this....https://github.com/ivanhoinacki/generator-angular-jspdf

Comment: I am fairly new to angular, can you make a fiddle

Comment: Please, provide some minimal example of code you actually tried and then I"ll be able to help you fix it. Otherwise, the example I gave should be far enough for you to get something useful.